# Convert string to datatable with c#

Tags: c#, string, datatable

I want to know how to convert this string to datatable.  This string is my string:

```
"<data name=\"Footer\" xml:space=\"preserve\"> <value>Digital Number</value> </data>,<data name=\"lblDisplay\" xml:space=\"preserve\"> <value>Hien thi</value> </data>"
```

I created table with 2 column named "Name" and "Value":

```
DataTable tbl = new DataTable();
DataColumn column;
DataRow row;
column = new DataColumn();
column.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
column.ColumnName = "Name";
tbl.Columns.Add(column);

column = new DataColumn();
column.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
column.ColumnName = "Value";
tbl.Columns.Add(column);
```

How can I convert the string to `DataTable`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The string you posted looks a lot like xml, but it is not valid xml.  It needs a root element (and remove the `,` comma).  I've updated below:

```
var xmlString = @"<?xml version=""1.0""?>
                  <rootData>
                      <data name=""Footer"" xml:space=""preserve""> 
                          <value>Digital Number</value> 
                      </data>
                      <data name=""lblDisplay"" xml:space=""preserve"">
                          <value>Hien thi</value> 
                      </data>
                  </rootData>";
```

`DataSet` has a method [`ReadXml()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.dataset.readxml?view=netframework-4.8) which

> ... provides a way to read either data only, or both
>   data and schema into a DataSet from an XML document...

Knowing that, now you can create a `DataSet` and use a `StringReader` to read the Xml straight into the DataSet.

```
var ds = new DataSet();
using (var reader = new StringReader(xmlString))
{
    ds.ReadXml(reader);
}
```

Then, all you need to do is extract the data from the DataSet:

```
Console.WriteLine($"{ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["name"]}: {ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["value"]}");

// output
Footer: Digital Number
```

If you want a DataTable just do:

```
 DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
```

See this [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/HLjgXh).

Comment: thanks so much for your help, i solved it with your ideal, my string acctually is from a resource file.